# How to find if two arrays contain any common item in SQL? With one array being my set result and the other a list of 'ids'?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, orm, typeorm

This is currently what my entities look like:

**Category Entity**

```
@Entity('category')
export class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', unique: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: "text", unique: true })
  @Index()
  slug: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Listing, (listing) => listing.categories, { cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  listings?: Listing[];

}
```

**Listing Entity**

```
@Entity('listing')
export class Listing extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.listings)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[];

}
```

**Query 1 (what I'm currently using)**

And this is currently what my query looks like:

```
const listings = await connection.getRepository()
      .createQueryBuilder('listing')
      .distinct(true)
      .leftJoinAndSelect('listing.categories', 'category', 'category.slug IN (:...slugs)', {slugs: [ 'mens-shirts', 'clearance' ]})
      .getMany()
```

**Query 1 Result**

```
[] // an empty list of Listings (Type: Listing[])
```

**Query 2 (checking to see if the innerJoinAndSelect was working properly)**

```
const listings = await connection.getRepository()
        .createQueryBuilder('listing')
        .distinct(true)
        .innerJoinAndSelect('listing.categories', 'category')
        .getMany();
```

**Query 2 Result**

```
[
  Listing {
    id: 'c24ea98d-da53-4f14-8706-a3597f3ee4d1',
    categories: [ [Category], [Category] ]
  },
  Listing {
    id: 'e8b3e680-85b6-4701-9ad7-bf65de348e76',
    categories: [ [Category], [Category] ]
  },
  Listing {
    id: '1bb04ea0-8435-44d6-856f-8eb53f24e941',
    categories: [ [Category], [Category] ]
  },
  Listing {
    id: '0735142d-fd38-4fad-b5a7-0356373dd0a3',
    categories: [ [Category], [Category] ]
  },
]
```

The `innerJoinAndSelect` method is working and giving me the results back, and I know why I'm getting an empty array when using the first query. It's because I'm trying to find the field `slug` on the Array of Categories, instead of each Category in the Array.

**Question:**
How would I search for the slug names `[ 'mens-shirts', 'clearance' ]`, in the array of Categories (Type: `Category[]`), using TypeORM's QueryBuilder? Or How could I check to see if each Category in the Categories field, has a slug, that is in `[ 'mens-shirts', 'clearance' ]`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `= ANY()` when searching if an element is inside an array. So change `'category.slug IN (:...slugs)'` to `'category.slug = ANY(:slugs)'` (notice how you don't need to use "spread" inside `ANY`, just reference the array directly)